# XML parsing Error while running Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am newbie to hibernate.I have tried my first hibernate program without success.I have got following error while running my hibernate program.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: Hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1586)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1520)
    at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:16)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: Error on line 11 of document  : The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup. Nested exception: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:482)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1576)
    ... 2 more
```

This is hibernate configuration file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- connecting database -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">test123</property>
<! -- autocommit false -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
<!-- for jdbc transaction -->
<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>

<mapping resource="mapping.hbm.xml">
</mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, your comment is not a comment:

```xml
<! -- autocommit false -->
```

Should be

```xml
<!-- autocommit false -->
```

You have an extra space...

You should be able to see that in source code highlighting - as demonstrated by the excellent SO source highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You have a comment bad delimited, search for this:

```
<! -- autocommit false -->
```

fix it by deleting the space beteen ! and --